# Preventing a change back once made in if statement python

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to change all the column values in 3 x 3 matrices to follow the following rules:

- If 0 -> 0
- If 1 -> 5
- If 2 -> 6
- If 3 -> 4
- If 4 -> 3
- If 5 -> 1
- If 6 -> 2
- If 7 -> 7
- If 8 -> 9
- If 9 -> 8

This is what I have been able to do so far

```
def solve(x):
    if x[x == 1].all() == True:
        x[x == 1] = 5
    if x[x == 5].all() == True:
        x[x == 5] = 1
    if x[x == 2].all() == True:
        x[x == 2] = 6
    if x[x == 6].all() == True:
        x[x == 6] = 2
    if x[x == 3].all() == True:
        x[x == 3] = 4
    if x[x == 4].all() == True:
        x[x == 4] = 3
    if x[x == 8].all() == True:
        x[x == 8] = 9
    if x[x == 9].all() == True:
        x[x == 9] = 8
    return x
```

The problem I'm having is that say a 1 goes to 5, how do I prevent it from going back to a 1 again? I've tried incorporating elif but it doesnt always yield the right results. For example say I ran this array into my function:

```
 array([[3, 1, 2],
        [3, 1, 2],
        [3, 1, 2]])
```

I'd expect to see

```
array([[4, 5, 6], 
       [4, 5, 6], 
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

But I end up getting the input again

```
array([[3, 1, 2],
       [3, 1, 2],
       [3, 1, 2]])
```

How can I work around this in the if statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some options, both use `d = {0: 0, 1: 5, 2: 6, ...}` to map `old_val: new_val`:

1. use `np.vectorize` to map `old_val: new_val`:

```
solved = np.vectorize(lambda i: d[i] if i in d else i)(arry)
```

2. Create a copy and change it to replaced version, using original array to check:

```
def solve(x):
    res = x
    for ov in d:
        res[x == ov] = d[ov]
    return res
```

Comment: Thats brilliant thanks for the help I like the dictionary and lambda function method very pythonic :)

Comment: @M00NKNIGHT no problem, note that the first method will fail if you have values not in `0-9` and the second will replace values not in `0-9` with `0`

Comment: @M00NKNIGHT Ok both now keep values that don't get replaced. But second version is more optimized.

Comment: Oh brilliant thank you @Moosefeather you've gone above and beyond